# facebook application asp.net javascript file errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I have created asp.net application and hosted on facebook.
but i cannot refer the javascript files .
they are referred in aspx pages as "Scripts/Jquey.js"
but while rendering application page in facebook.
it tries to look for.

```
     url/page.aspx/Scripts/Jquery.js
```

which it cant find.
how to overcome this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your path is relative to the root you should include the **tilde**, otherwise it will just be treated as relative to the page itself i.e. `~/Scripts/Jquery.js`.